# Sort an STL container of structs by a certain data member

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I know that this would be simpler with C++11, but is there a way to make it work in C++98? I have the following example code:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  foo(const int a_, const double b_): a(a_), b(b_) {}
  int a;
  double b;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const foo &f)
{
  out << f.a << ',' << f.b;
  return out;
}

#define DO_SORT(CONTAINER, TYPE, MEMBER) \
  std::sort(CONTAINER.begin(), CONTAINER.end(), boost::lambda::bind(&TYPE::MEMBER, boost::lambda::_1) > boost::lambda::bind(&TYPE::MEMBER, boost::lambda::_2));

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> v;
  v.push_back(foo(1, -2.0));
  v.push_back(foo(3, -3.0));
  v.push_back(foo(2, -1.0));

  std::cout << "Original" << std::endl;
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n");
  std::cout << "Sort by a" << std::endl;
  DO_SORT(v, foo, a);
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n");
  std::cout << "Sort by b" << std::endl;
  DO_SORT(v, foo, b);
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n");
}
```

This gets the job done, but it requires that the type inside of the container be specified. I'm looking for a way to be able to write just `DO_SORT(v, a)`. I tried replacing `TYPE` in the macro with `BOOST_TYPEOF(CONTAINER)::value_type` but the compiler didn't like that.

Is there any way to do this in C++98 without requiring that the type be specified? Also, if there's some way to reduce, or even remove, the use of macros in C++98, then that would be great as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That doesn't work, because CONTAINER is an instance of container and not the type itself.

Comment: Oops--I should have read more carefully. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the macro and get the type using template argument deduction with a pointer to member variable:

```
template <typename C, typename T, typename R>
void do_sort(C& container, R T::*mem) {
    std::sort(
        container.begin(), container.end(), 
        boost::lambda::bind(mem, boost::lambda::_1) > 
            boost::lambda::bind(mem, boost::lambda::_2));
}
```

Then call with the syntax

```
do_sort(v, &foo::a);
```

Which will thus instantiate:

```
void do_sort(std::vector<foo>& container, int foo::*mem);
```

`T` will deduce to `foo` and `R` will deduce to whatever `foo::a` is declared as, to yield the correct type for the pointer-to-member argument.  Side note: I'd name this function `sort_by` instead.  The general practice is also to use `<` for sorting instead of `>`, but if you want descending values then that's the way to go.

---

For the sake of completeness, here's how I would implement this in C++11

```
template <typename C, typename T, typename R>
void sort_by(C& container, R T::*mem) {
    std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container),
            [mem](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return lhs.*mem > rhs.*mem;} );
}
```

Comment: That does the trick. It still requires specifying the type in the container (i.e. foo) but it works without macros and I'll take it. Also, good call on the name `sort_by` and the use of the `> operator` was a copy and paste error when I was putting together the example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using this as an example for the general case, or would something like this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct foo {
  foo(const int a, const double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
  int a;
  double b;
};

bool compareA(const foo& foo1, const foo& foo2)
{
    return foo1.a < foo2.a;
}

bool compareB(const foo& foo1, const foo& foo2)
{
    return foo1.b < foo2.b;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> v;
  v.push_back(foo(1, -2.0));
  v.push_back(foo(3, -3.0));
  v.push_back(foo(2, -1.0));

  std::cout << "Original" << std::endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) std:: cout << v[i].a << '\n';
  std::cout << "Sort by a" << std::endl;
  std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), compareA );
  for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) std:: cout << v[i].a << '\n';
  std::cout << "Sort by b" << std::endl;
  std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), compareB );
  for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) std:: cout << v[i].b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I agree that works, but it requires a lot of "boiler plate" (definition of compare function and use of .begin()/.end()). I'm hoping for something with no required function definition and as simple an interface as possible in C++98/03 code.